# How can my website receive sms from mobile phone?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I want to receive message from mobile phone and display it on my website implemented PHP.

My site is a free messaging system that sends messages to mobile phones using chikka api.

I want to display messages from cell phones on my website. Is there any API available ?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know about the free API but SMS server is available once bought the SMS server they will provide the sample configuration script like API. we can customize that